# The given key was not present in the dictionary. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, syncfusion

I am facing Key not found exception while using the filtering in the Syncfusion Essential Grid.Please review the code and give me solution for that problem.

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +10715241
   Syncfusion.Shared.Mvc.LocalizationBase.GetLocalizedString(String key) +63
   Syncfusion.Mvc.Tools.DatePickerLocalizationString.get_closeText() +49
   Syncfusion.Mvc.Tools.jQueryDatePickerControl.OnInitScriptProcessed(String script) +1772
   Syncfusion.Mvc.Tools.jQueryUIControl.RegisterControlInitScript() +142
   Syncfusion.Mvc.Tools.jQueryUIControl.Render() +62




        <div class="sample-panel-margin" style="width: 100%;">
        @(Html.Syncfusion().Grid<EndDateResult>("Grid1")
      .ActionMode(ActionMode.JSON)
     .Datasource((IEnumerable<EndDateResult>)ViewData["data"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is due to the lacking of resource file for Date picker control. We have provided the common resource file for English; you can customize it based on the culture and use it in your sample.

**Resource file:** http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/115429/CommonResource.en-GB.resx-2059309917.zip

Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

Regards,

Abdul Matin M